# Orientation is locked to Landscape

Tags: android-layout

When I tried to lock my tab in portrait orientation mode and , the device is coming back to the Landscape mode. I am not able to lock it into portrait. Where do I need to change the Orientation? Is it in manifest or any Java file? How can i fix it into portrait?

Comment: add this in AndroidManifest.xml file inside <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Answer (score 0):

You Need to specify `screenOrientation` it in particular Activity you want to apply orientation in AndroidManifest, that's it.

```
 <activity

        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

 </activity>
```

Or

You can Do it programmatically by

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

& Add this to your Manifest

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```